# Can't resize a DIV at the click of button in Vue3

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3

I am trying to resize a DIV block using Vue3 but the button when I click it brings up an "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')". I know the JS part is wrong, but how do I correct it.

Here's the HTML part of the code

```
<div ref="block2">
<button v-on:click="changeWidth()"></button>
</div>
```

Heres the JS:

```
methods: {
    changeWidth:function()
            this.$refs.block2.style.width = "150px";
         }     
}
```

And this is the CSS styling on the DIV:

```
#block2{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #7d7d7d;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
```

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to perform the operation on button press, in my examples, there is always a variable to capture the current state and a variable for the input field. Of course, it could also be made dynamic so that resizing occurs simply when the input field changes without the need for a button press.

In Vue 3, I recommend abandoning the use of the Options API that was popular in Vue 2 and instead follow the guidelines of the Composition API. It lends a much more dynamic coding style to Vue.

#### Solution # 1: Resizing using the REF Element

I declared the container as a ref named `container`. Additionally, I created a `resize()` function that runs on button press. At that point, I pass the value of `currentValue` to the `style.width` and `style.height` attributes of the ref component.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const container = ref(null)
    const currentValue = ref(100)
    
    const resize = () => {
      container.value.style.width = `${currentValue.value}px`
      container.value.style.height = `${currentValue.value}px`
    }
    
    return { currentValue, container, resize }
  },
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #363635;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div ref="container" class="container"></div>
  
  <input v-model="currentValue" type="number" min="1">
  <button @click="resize">Resize container to {{ currentValue }}px</button>
</div>
```

#### Solution # 2: Resizing using the CSS attributes

I declared a variable called `nowValue`, in which I store the current pixel size of the container. I created a `resize()` function that runs on button press and copies the value of `currentValue` from the input into the `nowValue` variable. There are various ways to use `nowValue` in the CSS code; currently, I simply passed the values in a style HTML attribute. This way, when `nowValue` is updated, the DOM automatically takes on the new values.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const nowValue = ref(100)
    const currentValue = ref(100)
    
    const resize = () => {
      nowValue.value = currentValue.value
    }
    
    return { currentValue, nowValue, resize }
  },
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #363635;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container" :style="{ width: `${nowValue}px`, height: `${nowValue}px` }"></div>
  
  <input v-model="currentValue" type="number" min="1">
  <button @click="resize">Resize container to {{ currentValue }}px</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the JS has the problem also the HTML.
This is the correct code:
HTML:

```html
<div ref="block2" id="block2">
  <button v-on:click="changeWidth()">Resize</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
methods: {
  changeWidth: function() {
    const block2 = this.$refs.block2[0]; // Access the actual DOM element
    if (block2) {
      block2.style.width = "150px"; // Set the width property
    } else {
      console.error("Element with ref 'block2' not found");
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Silly, I just needed to add

```
id="block2"

All working fine....
```

Comment: To make this answer a bit more useful, could you please post the final state of your example? I assume you added the `id="block2"` to the div, but stating it explicitly would be better.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).